# VSTS: Use Docker on a Self-Hosted Windows 10 Agent

Tags: docker, windows-10, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would to use Docker on a Self-Hosted Windwos 10 Agent. To do so I installed Docker for Windows and was able to use it on the agent. But when I wanted to use it with a Docker task in VSTS I got the error:

> ```
> ##[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe failed 
>    with return code: 1
> ```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The agent service (`VSTS Agent (agentName)`) was running as `Network Service` what is not enough to use Docker. It is necessary to run the service in another context. Therefore:

Go to services

[image]

Search for the VSTS agent service

Right click on the service

Select properties

Go to the `Log On` tab

[image]

And select `Local System account`

Then restart the service

[image]

Now it is possible to use Docker. See also [Docker agent does not run under System Account](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/1003)

**EDIT:**

I encountered the problem also when the Docker service was running as `Local System`. In this context it was necessary to run the VSTS agent service as `Local System` too.